# Convert rdplot in the rdrobust library to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to convert an rdplot from the rdrobust library in R to a ggplot object? There are many specifications that do not work in the rdplot format (layout and grobs), so it would be nice to be able to work with the figure in another format.

Thanks!

Some random code for rdplot:

```
library(rdrobust)

theta <- 1:100
diff <- -50:49

rdplot(theta, diff, p=1, binselect="qs", nbins=c(15, 5))
```

Comment: Hi there, can you give us some code to produce an rdplot?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rdplot can be converted into a ggplot by accessing it via $rdplot:

```
p1 <- rdplot(theta, diff, p=1, binselect="qs", nbins=c(15, 5))

p1 <- p1$rdplot

> class(p1)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```